# how to remove 'Unsorted' option from the sorting option in Material React Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-react-table

I'm using "material-react-table" in a React JS project.

As per my requirements, I want to remove the 'Unsorted' option from the sorting in Material React Table.

Can anyone help me sort out this?

Thanks in advance.

node version: v16.15.0

React version: v18.2.0

material-react-table: ^1.14.0

Default one (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxLZ.png)

I need to remove the unsorted option. Only 'Ascending' and 'Descending' options should be there.

Comment: Maybe implement custom sorting function? https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/sorting#add-custom-sorting-functions

Answer (score 1):

```
<MaterialReactTable 
   table={table} 
   enableSortingRemoval={false}
/>
```

Use `enableSortingRemoval` props to remove the 'Unsorted' option from the sorting in Material React Table.

Visit https://github.com/KevinVandy/material-react-table/discussions/458